# unable to test a method which uses Observable in Jasmine

Tags: angular6, angular-test

My `Angular` application has a service `QuestionManagementService` which response on a `BackendService` to send `REST` messages. The `BackendService` in turn uses `HttpClient`. I am trying to test the `QuestionManagementService` in isolation.

The method I am testing is `addQuestion`

```
addQuestion(question:PracticeQuestion):any{
    console.log("In QuestionManagementService: addQuestion: ",question);
   this.bs.createQuestion(question).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log("add practice question - response is ",res);//I EXPECT THESE PRINTS TO SHOW BUT THEY DON'T
      let ev = <HttpEvent<any>>(res);
      if(ev.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        console.log('response from server: returning body '+ev.body);
        let isResponseStructureOK: boolean = this.helper.validateServerResponseStructure(ev.body);
        if (isResponseStructureOK) {
          let response:ServerResponseAPI = ev.body;
          console.log("received response from server: " + response.result);
          this.addQuestionSubject.next(new Result(response.result,response['additional-info']));

        } else {
          console.log("received incorrect response structure from server: ", ev.body);
          this.addQuestionSubject.next(new Result('error','Invalid response structure from server'));

        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("not response. ignoring");
      }
    },
    (error:ServerResponseAPI)=>{
      console.log("got error from the Observable: ",error);
      let errorMessage:string = this.helper.userFriendlyErrorMessage(error);
      this.addQuestionSubject.next(new Result('error',errorMessage));//TODOM - need to standardise errors

    },
    ()=>{ //observable complete
        console.log("observable completed")
      });
  }
```

As I am doing unit testing of `addQuestion`, I thought that I can mock the `createQuestion` method of the `BackendService`. The `spec` I have written so far is the following but I don't think it is correct as I don't see any prints on the console when the mocked response of `createQuestion` is received.

```
fit('should add a question',()=>{
    let backendService = TestBed.get(WebToBackendInterfaceService);
    let questionService = TestBed.get(QuestionManagementService);
    let question = new PracticeQuestion(...);

    const responseData = { result: 'success', ['additional-info']: 'question added successfully' };
    let httpResponseEvent:HttpResponse<any> = new HttpResponse<any>({body:responseData});
    //mock response of WebToBackendInterfaceService
    spyOn(backendService,'createQuestion').and.returnValue(new Observable(()=>{
      httpResponseEvent;
    }));

    questionService.addQuestion$.subscribe((res:Result)=>{
      console.log('received response from Question Services',res);
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
      let validResponse:boolean = ((res.result === 'success') || (res.result === 'initial')) ;
      expect(validResponse).toEqual(true);
    });
    questionService.addQuestion(question);
    expect(backendService.createQuestion).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was creating an `Observable` but I didn't push the value to an `Observer` using `next`. The correct implementation is (code snippet)

```
        spyOn(backendService,'createQuestion').and.returnValue(new Observable((subscriber)=>{ //subscriber or observer
      subscriber.next(httpResponseEvent)}
    ));
```

When creating an `Observable`, the Observable's constructor in Rxjs takes a `subscribe` function as argument. The definition of `subscribe` function is

```
(observer)=>{
/*logic of calculating values which Observer should produce and emit then using observer.next(value)*/
}
```

reference - http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

With the above code, the `this.bs.createQuestion(question)` returns a mock `Observable` whose `subscribe` function is

```
(subscriber)=>{ //subscribe function 
          subscriber.next(httpResponseEvent)
}
```

The above `subscribe` function will be called whenever any `Observer` subscribes to the `Observable`. So in code `.subscribe((res)=>{...}`, I subscribe to the mock `Observable` and now the `subscribe` function will emit the dummy value, `httpResponseEvent`  to my code. For those new to `Observables`, the `subscribe` function takes an `Observer` as argument. An `Observer` is an object which has 3 methods `next`, `error` and `complete`. Note that the `subscribe` function takes such an object

```
(res)=>{... },
    (error:ServerResponseAPI)=>{
     ...
    },
    ()=>{ //observable complete
        ...
      })
```